# Ajax call redirects to .fail method everytime

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery version 1.11.3 and after every successful response the ajax call goes to .fail method only. I want the success response to .done function. my response is 200 OK

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/contactslist/"+selectedoption,
  headers: {'cache-control': 'no-cache'},
  json: true,
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log("Successs: "+JSON.stringify(data));
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("Failed: "); 
});
```

Comment: I can't find the attribute `json` in jQuery documentation.

Comment: Pass jqXHR to fail function and check its value. It may give some idea about the issue. like .fail(function(jqXHR) { console.log(jqXHR);}

Answer (score 0):

Change JQuery version

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "populateData.htm", 
        dataType:"json", 
        data:"userId=SampleUser", 
        success:function(response){ 
            if (response.redirect) {
                window.location.href = response.redirect;
            }
            else {
                // Process the expected results...
            }
        }, 
     error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status); 
         } 

    }); 
});
```